# How to split array into two different array based on value?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array as shown below

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 0
    "item_code" => "abc001"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "item_code" => "abc002"
  ]
]
```

How can i split it into new array when id = 0?

```
// $newArr to store id = 0
0 => array:2 [▼
   "id" => 0
   "item_code" => "abc001"
]
// $oldArr to store id != 0
1 => array:2 [▼
   "id" => 1
   "item_code" => "abc002"
]
```

I want to store every id = 0 into $newArr and id !=0 into $oldArr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **$array** is a collection then try [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where)-

```
$new_array = $array->where('id','=',0);
$old_array = $array->where('id','!=',0);
```

If its a array then make it a collection first using [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#introduction)-

```
$array = collect($array);
```

Comment: Please explain you code ... I got error from your code.. Please tell me how it is working...?

Comment: we can query through collection object with where() method that is available with laravel. Have a look at this link please https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where

Comment: Okay... This is laravel project... I was running it in `core php`.. No  Issue.. Thanks...

Comment: Why is it show me Trying to get property of non-object error when i loop in blade? Is it return null value then caused the error?

Comment: try dd($single_object) and see in your loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use collection methods. First, wrap your array:

```
$collection = collect($array);
```

**1.** Use the [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where):

```
@foreach ($collection->where('id', 0) as $item)
    {{ $item['item_code'] }}
@endforeach

@foreach ($collection->where('id', '!=', 0) as $item)
    {{ $item['item_code'] }}
@endforeach
```

**2.** Use the [`partition()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-partition):

```
list($idIsZero, $idIsNotZero) = $collection->partition(function ($i) {
    return $i['id'] === 0;
});
```

In the most cases you don't need to transform collection back to array, but if you need to, use `->toArray()` on a collection.

Answer (score 2):

**INPUT**

```
$array = array(
    array("id" => 0,"item_code" => "abc001"),
    array("id" => 1,"item_code" => "abc002")
);
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$oldArray = array();
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    if($row['id']==0)$oldArray[] = $row;
    else $newArray[] = $row;
}
echo "New<pre>";print_r($newArray);echo "</pre>";
echo "Old<pre>";print_r($oldArray);echo "</pre>";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
New
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [item_code] => abc002
        )

)
Old
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [item_code] => abc001
        )

)
```